# bootstrap-select not dropdown in angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

Copy/paste and execute this in index.html of angular project:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular12</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />  
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <app-root></app-root> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">  
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
      <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
      <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
    </select>
    <span class="help-inline">With <code>data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"</code>. Try searching for california</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Yhe module app.module.ts:

```
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth-guard.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers/customers.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//** ngx-translate
//import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { CustomersEditPopupComponent } from './customers-edit-popup/customers-edit-popup.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './upload/upload.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './_helpers/alert';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,  './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
//**

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CustomersComponent,
    AppComponent,
    CustomersEditPopupComponent,
    UploadComponent,
    AlertComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },      
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'customers', component: CustomersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'customers/edit', component: CustomersEditPopupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'customers/edit/:id', component: CustomersEditPopupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ["localhost:44330"],
        blacklistedRoutes: []
      }
    }),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  })

  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  // <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 }
```

Sample on: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

---

Is only html! Not working, select doesn't dropdown... why?
I don't want to use any external module pls..................................................................................................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
Thx

Comment: Please check the link=> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-select-eg-pfr9we?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Your dropdown is working. Can you show your app.module.ts or you modules file. I think something is missing there.

Comment: Sample of data-live-search in developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples. ISearch box not appear in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-select-eg-pfr9we?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html because you missing  class="selectpicker"   in your example. If i try to doing by JQuery with  $('.my-select').selectpicker(); show error TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Comment: You must call `$('.select').selectpicker();` in `onInit()` method as first line.

Answer (score 0):

Uggly solution from
https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2040

"Above solution didnt work for me. What i did was removing all the styles and scripts from angular.json and placing them on index.html. In that way, it started working fine. I am on Angular 9."

Alternative is appreciated